# using stokes' theorem with curl zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Use Stokes’ theorem to solve the following integral (each time the curve is oriented counterclockwise when viewed from above):

$$\int \limits_C (y + z)dx + (z + x)dy + (x + y)dz$$ where $C$ is the intersection of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 2y$ and the plane $y = z$.

Would this be zero? Because when you calculate the curlF, which you use in the theorem, you get zero don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Another way to see $\operatorname{curl}F = 0$ is to realize that it's the gradient of the scalar field $\phi(x,y,z) = xy + yz + zx$.